# tkinter resize and reposition unintentionally

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, raspberry-pi

How to fix the size and position of a Label and Image in tkinter? 
I have uploaded the code in raspberry pi 0 and it displays in the exact size and position. Days pass, the Image become bigger or smaller and also the Label. Can someone help me?

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time
import datetime

root = tkinter.Tk()

def close_escape(event=None):
print("\n ESCAPED")
root.destroy()

root.overrideredirect(True)
root.overrideredirect(False)
#root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.geometry("600x500")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
root.focus_set()
root.bind("<Escape>", close_escape)

#### header
wid=200;hei=90
logo = Image.open('logo.png')
logo = logo.resize((wid, hei), Image.ANTIALIAS)
l = ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo)
panel = tkinter.Label(root, image=l)
panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")
panel.place(x=1,y=0)

##body
wid=200;hei=200
im_temp = Image.open('user.png')
im_temp = im_temp.resize((wid, hei), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im_temp)
panel = tkinter.Label(root, image=img)
panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")
panel.place(x=60,y=150)

name= Label(root, text='Name:', font='Tahoma 14')
name.place(x=290, y=165)
nID= Label(root, text='ID Number:', font='Tahoma 14')
nID.place(x=290, y=265)
usrnme = Label(root, font="Georgia 35")
usrnme['text'] = "Full Name"
usrnme.place(x=330,y=195)
idnum = Label(root, font="Tahoma 25")
idnum['text'] = "ID Number"
idnum.place(x=330,y=300)
```